# How to get the emaiil id from facebook if i login with phone number in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am integrating the facebook integration in the iOS application for login in my application.
Is it possible to get the email id from the facebook API in iOS if we login through the facebook by using phone number.
Currently i am using the following code.

```
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Process error
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
    } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing

        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {
                         NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                     }
                 }];
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: can you print the result  NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik if we login through email id i am getting the email id but what about if i login with phone number.

Comment: if your facebook account created by Mobile number and you haven't added email_id then you can't get the email_id. but in your facebook account has any email_id added. so you can get it. other wise email field is blank every time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get email address if user has signed up with email. In case of user has signed up with phone number you may get email field as empty. Please have a look at Facebook developers reference.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email

> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.